# (iphone) does my app get listed in "what's new" when publishing to new countries?

Tags: iphone, publish

I'm planning to publish my app to set of countries first then publish to other countries as the app matures.

Would my app get listed in "what's new" in the newly added countries or "what's new" is only allowed for first publish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer from someone who tried this and he says, it's "first publish only" from his experience.
Although he did say that "what's new" doesn't impact your sales much.

bleh..

Answer (score 0):

It should be listed, every country has it's own App Store, it's logical that it should be listed. I hope that Apple knows it's logical :)